# getting marker information from XML/KML

Tags: xml, google-maps, gps, google-maps-markers

Is there a way to get marker information from this style of XML/KML document ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
   <Document>
    <Placemark>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>4.4852,51.52229,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
   </Document>
</kml>
```

Now we need to change the gps coordinates so the useable format for us should be: 51.52229,4.4852.

How to load this gps coordinates in a variable and put them in our map in V3 code.
We have tryed this code but it doesnt work.

```
 // Stormchasers locaties inladen  
 downloadUrl("https://www.followmee.com/kml.aspx?token=b327299e-33e7-4b56-96ef-88d812544686", function(data) {

var xml = xmlParse(data);

var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Point");

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

  var path = [];

  var points = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("coordinates");

    path.push(point);

    var marker = createMarker(latlng);

    marker.setMap(map); 

}



 }); 

 function createMarker(latlng) {
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: latlng,
});
return marker;
 }
 // Einde Iconen inladen
```

Could someone help us ?

Thank you!

Comment: You have to parse the coordinates out of the element content and use them to create the latlng (and probably push that latlng onto the path array rather than an XML element).  See the source for [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) for an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) parses KML coords, the code below was extracted from the processPlacemarkCoords function.  Since you only have single sets of coordinates, in your example, you can do this (point will be a google.maps.LatLng object with the desired coordinates), if you need to handle polylines or polygons, you will need to do more.

```
    var coords = geoXML3.nodeValue(coordNodes[j]).trim();
    coords = coords.replace(/,\s+/g, ',');
    coords = coords.split(',');
    if (!isNaN(coords[0]) && !isNaN(coords[1])) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(coords[1]), 
        parseFloat(coords[0]))
    } else alert("bad coordinates, not numbers");


//nodeValue: Extract the text value of a DOM node, with leading and trailing whitespace trimmed
geoXML3.nodeValue = function(node, defVal) {
  var retStr="";
  if (!node) {
    return (typeof defVal === 'undefined' || defVal === null) ? '' : defVal;
  }
   if(node.nodeType==3||node.nodeType==4||node.nodeType==2){
      retStr+=node.nodeValue;
   }else if(node.nodeType==1||node.nodeType==9||node.nodeType==11){
      for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;++i){
         retStr+=arguments.callee(node.childNodes[i]);
      }
   }
   return retStr;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this, so if i should add something like this it would do the trick ?

'<script type="text/javascript">
var myMap = new google.maps.Map("http://maps.google.pt/?ll=46.55886,5.581055&spn=8.052504,19.753418&t=k&vpsrc=6&z=6");
var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: myMap});
myParser.parse('my.kml');
</script>'

Comment: I can't tell (code in comments is _really_ hard to read...  you do need to include the geoxml3 third party library if you are going to use it though.